# Creating instances of a JavaFX Video Player class

Tags: java, javafx

Fairly new to Java and trying to teach myself a little about JavaFX.  I'm trying to create a simple JavaFX video/media player that runs when I click a video file. 
I want to create the actual player as a separate class that accepts the video file location as an a string argument.

When I run the below,

```
public class BLPlayer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0){
            VideoPlayer vp = new VideoPlayer(args);
        }else{
            //showGUI();
        }
    }
}


public class VideoPlayer extends Application {
    String path;
    MediaPlayer player;
    Scene scene;
    MediaView view;
    Group root;
    Media media;

    VideoPlayer(String[] args){
        path = args[0];
        path = path.replace("\\", "/"); 
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        File f = new File(path);

        root = new Group();
        media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        player.play();
    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class player.VideoPlayer
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:884)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: player.VideoPlayer.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1812)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$7.run(LauncherImpl.java:790)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
```

I don't know why it isn't working.  I'd appreciate any tips or advice!  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you need to launch the JavaFX application using the `launch()`. For more details [go through this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24615689/1759128).

If you really need to send parameters to the VideoPlayer class. You can fetch the parameters using the `getParameters()` of the `Application` class.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Application {
    String path;
    MediaPlayer player;
    Scene scene;
    MediaView view;
    Group root;
    Media media;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parameters params = getParameters();
        final List<String> parameters = params.getRaw();
        path = !parameters.isEmpty() ? parameters.get(0) : "";
        path = path.replace("\\", "/"); 
        root = new Group();
        File f = new File(path);
        root = new Group();
        media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        player.play();
    }
}
```

To inititate the JavaFX application from another class

```
public class BLPlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0){
            Application.launch(VideoPlayer.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```